# How can I get the count of a list in an Entity Framework model without including/loading the entire collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model in Entity Framework Core that goes something like this:

```
public class Anime
{
     public int EpisodeCount { get { return Episodes.Count() } }
     public virtual ICollection<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having the issue of EpisodeCount being `0`. The solution currently is to run a `.Include(x => x.Episodes)` within my EF query, but that loads the entire collection of episodes where it's not needed. This also increases my HTTP request time, from 100ms to 700ms which is just not good.

I'm not willing to sacrifice time for simple details, so is there a solution where I can have EF only query the COUNT of the episodes, without loading the entire collection in?

I was suggested to do this

```
var animeList = context.Anime.ToPagedList(1, 20);
animeList.ForEach(x => x.EpisodeCount = x.Episodes.Count());
return Json(animeList);
```

but this also returns `0` in EpisodeCount, so it's not a feasible solution.

Comment: I would just set `EpisodeCount` using a separate `Episodes.Count()` query. `.Include()` is going to perform a `JOIN`.

Comment: As usual, create ViewModel / DTO class and populate with (presumably) server side query. e.g. the equivalent of `context.Anime.Select(a => new { Anime = a, EpisodeCount = a.Episodes.Count() }`

Comment: @IvanStoev That suggestion you gave me, it's turned my request time into 20seconds or so with this output: https://hastebin.com/zoyigilico.pl

Comment: @bin Oops, sorry, I was looking from EFC side. It has to be something that `PagedList` is doing.

Comment: @IvanStoev after directly copy/pasting your code, it seems to work but it's taken my request time to 600ms again, which is what I wanted to prevent. Looking in logs it *is* performing a COUNT(*) on the query. It's performing that query on EVERY episode, which is an issue.

Comment: Yep, still have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: What EFC version are you on?

Comment: @IvanStoev Entity Framework Core 2.0

Comment: Looks like in order to get single SQL query translation, you need to project the entity properties directly to the view model or entity (AutoMapper could help with that). Anyway, something like this should work `context.Anime.Select(a => new { Anime = new Anime { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name, ...}, EpisodeCount = a.Episodes.Count() }`

Comment: @bin, I guess I miss something: Does `Episodes` contain items? If it is, why do you get a count of 0? If it's not, why do you expect count other than 0?

Comment: @HeyJude Because EF should translate it into an SQL query that grabs the COUNT(*) of the episodes, instead of load it all into memory (which also, won't happen without .Include()), which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @bin, then Ivan's last suggestion should do the job

Comment: @IvanStoev I implemented this but it's still taking 300-400ms https://hastebin.com/ekudocogoq.php (though still a huge improvement so thanks for the help). It's still spamming the database with COUNT() queries.

Comment: I think the SQL `COUNT()` is unavoidable. But noticed `GenreIds = anime.AnimeGenres.Select(c => c.GenreId)` inside the projection, this would cause N + 1 queries as well. Which as of now (and also in the incoming 2.1 release) cannot be workarounded. EF6 processes such queries much better.

Comment: Unfortunately EF6 isn't cross-platform which is my only limitation. If only EFC would combine all the COUNT queries into one giant COUNT query. Other than that this solution is really great so I'll hit your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to project the desired data into a special class (a.k.a. ViewModel, DTO etc.). Unfortunately (or not?), in order to avoid N + 1 queries the projection must not only include the count, but all other fields as well.

For instance:

*Model:*

```
public class Anime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    public virtual ICollection<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
}
```

*ViewModel / DTO:*

```
public class AnimeInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    public int EpisodeCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following code:

```
var animeList = db.Anime.Select(a => new AnimeInfo
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    EpisodeCount = a.Episodes.Count()
})
.ToList();
```

produces the following single SQL query:

```
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Name], (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM [Episode] AS [e]
     WHERE [a].[Id] = [e].[AnimeId]
) AS [EpisodeCount]
FROM [Anime] AS [a]
```

Comment: Is there a smarter way to write the select? Because if `Anime` and `AnimeInfo` contains 20 other properties, it would require a crazy amount of lines in the select lambda function.

Comment: @Joel'-' Out of the box - no. You need some 3rd party library, for instance AutoMapper.